# How to remove the warning that appears about resignFirstResponder when using interactive keyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

This is only a warning and the app works fine but there might be a reason for this warning to be there.

I found similar issues on the web but no answers yet.
first, the error:

> [View] First responder warning: '; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {302, 20};
>   adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>' rejected resignFirstResponder
>   when being removed from hierarchy

The setup is a chatviewcontroller so it's a UITableView embedded inside a UIViewController that contains cells with text.

We are using the **Dismiss Interactively** keyboard function of the UIScrollView class to be able to dismiss the keyboard when we swipe down on the list of chat items.

We add an inputAccessory to the keyboard to be used as a text input area + send button.

In the UIViewController that contains the UITableView, we add the following UIResponder override to get the accessoryView.

```
override var inputAccessoryView: UIView {
    return messageInputView
  }
```

The problem is that we dismiss interactively the keyboard (so that it disappear from the screen), we get this warning.
Any input, any help on the topic would be great!

Comment: I also have a little but noticeable lag in scrolling when this error logged

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that if you override the `viewWillTransition` function and call `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()` in it, it will fix the problem!

Comment: That’s great if you have a collectionview I guess